# Logging into my desktop from SSH says I have no updates, but I do

Tags: ssh, apt, upgrade

When I SSH into my Ubuntu Desktop, I get some output saying:

```
0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
```

However, running `sudo apt-get upgrade` tells me that a package (numix-icon-theme) can be upgraded. Is there a reason that I'm told there are no updates?

Comment: I relogged on a second ssh session with the first still open running `apt-get update`, so it may have been the update, or the relog. I'll check it out when I have more updates, though, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is either:

1. there's a bug in the `~/.profile` or `/etc/profile` (or wherever) code which detects and counts the available updated packages.
2. `apt-get update` hasn't been run recently (i.e. since the updated package was made available).  There's probably a cron job that runs `apt-get update` periodically.  If it's important to you, modify the crontab entry so that it runs more frequently.

Comment: It doesn't bother me at all, I just thought it was just pretty interesting. Thanks for the help!